# How to convert player move method to class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I am trying to convert a method responsible for dealing with player movement to a class that is able to run the code properly. However, I am extremely inexperienced with classes and cannot figure out why my code comes up with endless errors about not existing in the current format. I would appreciate it if someone could please push me in the right direction with how to do this. Below I have my code I want to move to a class.

```
 var button = (Button)sender;
                button.Text = playerchoice.ToString();
                button.Enabled = false;
                consolelistbox.Items.Add("Player has selected " + button.Name + " to put their " + playerchoice.ToString());
                buttons.Remove(button);
                numberofturns += 1;
                PlayerWinConditions(playerchoice);
                TieConditions();
                playerturn = false;
```

Comment: If you want us to fix your class you'll need to show us the code you've got so far

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to create a class...

- Right click in your project.

[image: Then...]

-Then you just paste the code into the class